# Issue with Oracle ODBC

Tags: windows, oracle, odbc

I have a server with an Oracle Database. Using Navicat I can connect to the Database and see the database tables, run queries etc.

I am trying to add ODBC support for Oracle to be used with Crystal Reports.

What I have done so far:
I struggled to install instant client and get it working as shown in some guides. As suggested I downloaded ODAC which bundled on the Oracle ODBC Driver and Instant Client etc.

After installing I had Oracle installed in C:\app\Administrator\product\12.1.0\client_1

I added two Environmental Variable:

```
%ORACLE_HOME% to go to C:\app\Administrator\product\12.1.0\client_1
%TNS_ADMIN% - to go to C:\app\Administrator\product\12.1.0\client_1\Network\Admin
```

Once added, I then went to control panel->Administrative Tools->ODBC.

I clicked system DSN and added the connection. The connection was successful.

However, when selecting the ODBC connection via Crystal Reports, the Database is showing the database functions (I assume stored functions as they appear in the functions section for the DB in Navicat). I cannot however, see the actual database tables.

Has anyone else experienced this issue and if so does anyone know how to resolve this. Many thanks for your time

Comment: Last time I used Crystal Reports it was extremely picky about the versions of all products.  Find a support matrix in the product documentation and verify that Crystal Reports version A works on Windows B with Oracle Client C and Oracle Server D.  And also check 32 bit vs 64 bit.

Comment: @jonearles many thanks for the advice, I will certainly check this out. I have a feeling you may be correct.